# change background color of textview from another class

Tags: android

Say for example I have a textview in class A,
and I want to change background color of textview from class B through a method...
how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `tvView` being passed is associated with a valid control (ie, `findViewById()` has been called before calling this function)

```
class B
{
public void changeBG(TextView tvView)
{
        tvView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

}
};
```

Comment: Hey St0le

its giving me java.lang.NullPointerException
i hv to do this "findViewById" in class A or class B?

Comment: `TextView tvTest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_id)` This should be in the `Activity` class. you can then pass this Variable Around and use it anywhere in any class.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you better have a public method changeBG in class A.
call that changeBG from Class B.

Comment: actually, its working, but my textview is not visible after changing its background color..

Comment: I hope you have used the contrasting colors as background and foreground. so that the text is visible. :)